# Using "Attribute to Attribute" map in Hive XML SerDe

Tags: xml, hadoop, xpath, hive, hiveql

I have an XML document that looks something like the below:

```
<root>
 <unwanted>
  ...
 </unwanted>
 <wanted version="A">
  <unwanted2 type='1'>
   ...
  </unwanted2>
  <unwanted2 type='2'>
   ...
  </unwanted2>
  <unwanted2 type='3'>
   ...
  </unwanted2>
  <wanted2>
   <detail>
    <row date="Jan-17" price="100" inventory="50">
    <row date="Feb-17" price="101" inventory="40">
    <row date="Mar-17" price="102" inventory="30">
   </detail>
  </wanted2>
 </wanted>
 <wanted version="B">
  <unwanted2 type='1'>
   ...
  </unwanted2>
  <unwanted2 type='2'>
   ...
  </unwanted2>
  <unwanted2 type='3'>
   ...
  </unwanted2>
  <wanted2>
   <detail>
    <row date="Jan-17" price="200" inventory="60">
    <row date="Feb-17" price="201" inventory="70">
    <row date="Mar-17" price="202" inventory="80">
   </detail>
  </wanted2>
 </wanted>
</root>
```

I would like to import the file into a `Hive` table, preferably into this format:

```
Version | Date   | Price | Inventory
A         Jan-17   100     50
A         Feb-17   101     40
A         Mar-17   102     30
B         Jan-17   200     60
B         Feb-17   201     70
B         Mar-17   202     80
```

But I would settle for now for importing it as a map of dates and prices:

```
version | spot_date
A         {Date: Jan-17, Price: 100, Inventory: 50}
A         {Date: Feb-17, ...}
A         {Date: Mar-17, ...}
B         {Date: Jan-17, ...}
B         {Date: Feb-17, ...}
B         {Date: Mar-17, ...}
```

I am trying to use [XMLSerDe for Hive](https://github.com/dvasilen/Hive-XML-SerDe/), and use the "[attribute to attribute](https://github.com/dvasilen/Hive-XML-SerDe/wiki/XML-data-sources#43-attribute-to-attribute)" feature.

My query looks like the below:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ppa_test(
    version        STRING, 
    spot_date      MAP<STRING,STRING>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
    "column.xpath.version"="/wanted/@version",
    "column.xpath.spot_date"="/wanted/wanted2/detail/row",
    "xml.map.specification.row"="date->@date"
)
STORED AS
INPUTFORMAT 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
TBLPROPERTIES (
"xmlinput.start"="<wanted ",
"xmlinput.end"="</wanted>"
);
```

But when I load in my data I get:

```
version | spot_date
A         {"row":"Mar-17"}
B         {"row":"Mar-17"}
```

If I instead change the `xml.map.spec` path to:

```
"xml.map.specification.row"="@date->@price"
```

I can read each row of XML separately, but it is recorded into the same Hive table row, and also I would prefer use the attribute name:

```
Version | spot_date
A         {"Mar-17":"102", "Feb-17":"101", "Jan-17":"100"}
B         {"Mar-17":"202", "Feb-17":"201", "Jan-17":"200"}
```

1. How can I record each XML `row` node into its own Hive record
2. How can I use the attribute name (or a custom string) as the key?

---

**Edit**

So changing from `spot_date MAP<STRING,STRING>` to...

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ppa_test(
    scenario    STRING, 
    spot_date   array<struct<
        date:      string, 
        price:     string, 
        inventory: string, 
    >>
)...
```

Gives me an array of objects

```
Version | spot_date
A         [{date: Jan-17, price: 100, inventory: 50},
           {date: Feb-17, price: 101, inventory: 40},
           {date: Mar-17, price: 102, inventory: 30}]
B         [{date: Jan-17, ... ]
```

Which accomplishes #2 from above, but still not sure about #1

Answer (score 0):

You can explode the array of structures you created for #2 to get #1.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ppa_test(
    scenario    STRING, 
    spot_date   ARRAY<STRUCT<spotdates: struct<
        date:      string, 
        price:     string, 
        inventory: string, 
    >>>
)
```

You can use Lateral View for this

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ppa_test_exploded;
CREATE TABLE ppa_test_exploded as
 SELECT scenario,
  SD.spotdates.date as date,
  SD.spotdates.price as price,
  SD.spotdates.inventory as inventory
  FROM ppa_test
  LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(spot_date) exploded as SD;
```

Hope this helps.